# How to create Tab Delimited Select statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql, plsql

I need to combine columns with select statment such that it create a tab delimited file.

For. e.g

```
Select ColumnA || "," || ColumnB
```

Above statement will create Comma Seperate File. What should I write to create Tab delimited file?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MySQL:

```
select concat(ColumnA, "\t" ,ColumnB)
```

SQL Server:

```
select ColumnA + char(9) + ColumnB
```

Oracle:

```
select ColumnA || chr(9) || ColumnB
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you should try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(ColumnA, '\t', ColumnB)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tab is `char(9)` in Microsoft SQL Server.

source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187323.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Postgresql:

```
select concat(ColumnA, chr(9), ColumnB)
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite:

```sql
select ColumnA || char(9) || ColumnB
```